# i would like to convert oracle function to big query can some one let me know the best way

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
 NVL (SUBSTR (ARY_TE, INSTR (ARY_TE,   '|',  1,   3)  + 1,
                          INSTR (ARY_TE, '|',  1,  4)  - INSTR (ARY_TE,  '|', 3)- 1), '@@')   LNG_TE,
```

**Explanation:** The data is separated by the delimiter | and they are using the data from the position of the particular column to fetch the data between the pipes based on position and adding with  1

Now, what I want is the right syntax to use in BigQuery.

Here in the data we have delimiter as | where we use the place 1,3 value to pick from the data at 
sample data `{ @@|1.0|2.3|2.3|@@|@@|1.0|@@|@@}`

Sample output: 
1.25(approx not the out pot from that query)

Comment: Please post some sample output.

Comment: Hi the out put is in the form numeric values 11.25 etc

Comment: where this 11.25 came from? please explain!

Comment: that is not the exact  out put  its just sample

Comment: so how you think we will help you if you don't even give us the logic you expect? you should give us expected result based on example of input you provided!

Comment: Hello Srikanth, we need this: Please provide examples like "for the input X the output is Y". We need your values for X and Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPLIT(column_name, '|') [SAFE_OFFSET(4)] )

this will pick the value where you want the data from an the offset value